# Creating your own TRAP exception handler?

Tags: assembly, exception, 68000, motorola-trap

I am currently learning assembly language using the M68000 and am having trouble figuring out how to use the TRAP 5 through 13 instructions. I cant seem to find any examples online on someone creating their own TRAP instructions. For example how would you write a simple TRAP#6 instruction to switch the state of the processor. (user state or supervisor state).

Comment: please post your sample code, errors if you have with your question

Answer (score 3):

Writing a trap handler is not trivial, and especially switching privilege mode is hairy (because it not just changes the privilege mode, but also switches between the two or three stack pointers the CPU has: USP/MSP/ISP).

The next hurdle is that each 68K family member uses its own set of stack frames, meaning what is pushed onto the SSP differs depending on the actual CPU model (the 68000 being the "worst" offender because the original set of stack frames has no identification field, unlike the higher model which have a common frame format indicator word).
Stack frame formats are documented in the M68K Familiy manual, which you can find online.

Third problem is to actually install your handler. You have to locate the vector for the trap in memory, which can be relocated to *any* address in all 68K CPUs except the 68000 through the VBR register. Not to mention you can't access the VBR in user mode.

Fourth, trap vectors are almost always under OS control, so changing a trap vector may break the system. User trap vectors may or may not be supported through OS specific means.

For a working demo for *just* the 68000 you can look up the vector number and stack frame format from the family manual and just point that vector to your own code. I suggest starting with something trivially simple such as just changing a registers value in the trap handler and then confirm it works before trying stunts like privilege changes.

Comment: In case you're working on the bare metal, make sure your supervisor stack is properly initialized.